# Action Url code doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Assign", "Teacher")?teacherId=" + assignId;
```

the code above is not working, I have Update view and its controller, I dont know why it is not working,the page just refresh not redirect.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using it in javascript file or in razor view?

Comment: Provide more code, maybe something crash before this redirecting.

Comment: can you try this : window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Assign?teacherId=" + assignId, "Teacher");

Comment: Show us the resulting `a` tag that is generated. Where does the link need to go to?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this using replace the url beacuse can't use javascript variable with new keyword in url.action.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Assign", "Teacher", new {assignId = "teacherId"})';

window.location.href = url.replace('teacherId', assignId);
```

Answer (score 0):

should you pass it in this way:

```
 public ActionResult Assign(int assignId)   //<-- Your  Action

 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Assign", "Teacher" , new {assignId= "teacherId"})'.replace("teacherId", parseInt(assignId));
```